# INSERT id from other column or NULL if value does not exist

Tags: mysql, insert

**THE DATA**

I have a set of data in the following format:

```
CAR_MAKE TABLE
ID      MAKE
1       Ford
2       Tesla
3       Acura
4       Honda
5       Toyota


MAKE_NOTES TABLE
NOTE_ID MAKE_ID MAKE_NAME   NOTE
1       1       Ford        New QNX-Based Sync System
2       2       Tesla       Looking forward to Model 3
3       5       Toyota      Updated Corolla 2018
4       Null    Ferrari     Very Fast and Very Red
```

I know there's repeating data (make_name) between table 1 and table 2.  Let's assume I can't mess with the data.  I also can't guarantee that an entry would have been made in car_make first.  In such a case make_notes.make_id should be null.

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

What I'm trying to do is INSERT a row into make_notes, inserting null into make_id if it does not exist in car_make, otherwise inserting car_make.id.

This works fine if, make_name exists in car_make... but if I attempt to insert a record with a make_name that does not exist in car_make, no record is inserted (no error is thrown either).

```
INSERT INTO make_notes (
    make_id,
    make_name,
    note
)
SELECT
    id,
    'ford',
    'New Note'
FROM car_make
WHERE make = 'ford';
```

I've also tried to use this as a subquery:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM car_make where make = 'Ferrari') = 1)
        THEN car_make.id
        ELSE null
    END AS make_id
FROM car_make;
```

I have not been albe intergrate it into my main query without throwing an error.  As a stand alone query it returns one row for each entry in car_make, as null if 'Ferrari' does not exist, and each id if it does.

**QUESTION**

How do I create an insert query that will insert into 'make_notes', and insert 'null' if make_name does not exist in car_make, and insert car_make.id if make_name does exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using an [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) clause should work for your case:

```
INSERT INTO `make_notes` (
    make_id,
    make_name,
    note
)
VALUES(
    IF(
        ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `car_make` WHERE `make` = 'ford') > 0),
        (SELECT `id` FROM `car_make` WHERE `make` = 'ford'),
        NULL
    ),
    'ford',
    'New note'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with one query. I think you have to run a `select` to get the ID from the car_make table. Then you do the insert.